# How can I dynamic-load model on subroute with dva.js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

1. I want to dynamic-load model on sub-route, because the model can be very big , and 
   the model is dynamic-generated sometimes(with dynamic `namespace`).
   [the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfxy.jpg)
2. This is my code. I imported `app` from `/src/index.js`

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import modelExtend from 'dva-model-extend'
   import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
   import dynamic from 'dva/dynamic'
   import app from '../../../index'

   function StepRoutes({ match }) {
     const id = match.params.id
     const routes = [{
       path: `${match.url}/class-maintenance`,
       models: () => [modelExtend(ClassBasicModel, { namespace: `class-maintenance-${id}` })],
       component: () => import('./ClassMaintenance'),
     }, {
       path: `${match.url}/course-selection`,
       models: () => [import('./CourseSelection/basicModel')],
       component: () => import('../Steps/CourseSelection'),
     }]
     return (
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (<Redirect to={`${match.url}/class-maintenance`} />)} />
         {
           routes.map(({ path, ...dynamics }, index) => (
             <Route
               key={index}
               exact
               path={path}
               component={dynamic({ app, ...dynamics })}
             />
           ))
         }
       </Switch>
     )
   }

   export default StepRoutes
   ```

2.Then, the model did dynamic-loaded when switch to the route but with `Warning`. How can I solve this problem ?
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUstR.png)